# why do i get different outputs when i basically copied the code?(deletion of node and replacement with deepest node)

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am trying to delete and replace a node with the deepest node but my program only removes the node.

I studied a code i found on internet and copied the code but i am getting a different output than the original program.

original output:

```
Inorder traversal before deletion : 7 11 12 10 15 9 8 
Inorder traversal after deletion : 7 8 12 10 15 9
```

my program:

```
Inorder traversal before deletion : 7 11 12 10 15 9 8 
Inorder traversal after deletion : 7 12 10 15 9 8
```

I need help in understanding why it is so? and how to fix it?.

original program -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deletion-binary-tree/

my program

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct Node 
{
int key;
struct Node* left;
struct Node* right;
};

struct Node* newNode(int key)
{
struct Node* temp= new Node;
temp->key=key;
temp->left=temp->right=NULL;
return temp;
}

void inorder(struct Node* temp)
{
if(!temp)
return;

inorder(temp->left);
cout<<temp->key<<" ";
inorder(temp->right);
}

void deletDeepest(struct Node* root,struct Node* d_node)
{
queue <struct Node*>  q;
q.push(root);
struct Node* temp;
while(!q.empty())
{
temp = q.front();
q.pop();

if(temp==d_node)
{
temp=NULL;
delete(d_node);
return;
}
if(temp->right)
{
if(temp->right==d_node)
{
temp->right=NULL;
delete(d_node);
return;
}
else 
q.push(temp->right);
}
if(temp->left)
{
if(temp->left==d_node)
{
temp->left=NULL;
delete(d_node);
return;
}
else 
q.push(temp->left);
}

}
}

void deletion(struct Node* root, int key)
{
struct Node* temp;
struct Node* key_node=NULL;
queue <struct Node*> q;
q.push(root);
while(!q.empty())
{
temp=q.front();
q.pop();

if(temp->key==key)
key_node=temp;

if(temp->right)
q.push(temp->right);

if(temp->left)
q.push(temp->left);
}

int x = temp->key;
deletDeepest(root,temp);
key_node->key=x;
}

int main()
{
    struct Node* root = newNode(10); 
    root->left = newNode(11); 
    root->left->left = newNode(7); 
    root->left->right = newNode(12); 
    root->right = newNode(9); 
    root->right->left = newNode(15); 
    root->right->right = newNode(8); 

    cout << "Inorder traversal before deletion : "; 
    inorder(root); 

    int key = 11; 
    deletion(root, key); 

    cout << endl; 
    cout << "Inorder traversal after deletion : "; 
    inorder(root); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) please.

Comment: [copied to code from the link, got the same output as on the page](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oZRn1e1GxO7vWztV). What did you change on the code? Make a diff

Answer (score 0):

That's a non traditional order:

```
if(temp->right)
q.push(temp->right);

if(temp->left)
q.push(temp->left);
}
```

Looking at the original its also a different order to the original.

Comment: thanks, can't believe a simple change in order changed the functionality of the function.

Comment: `Turn Left, Walk 10, Turn Right` Now got back to the start and try `Turn Right, Walk 10, Turn Left` You end up facing the same way but in completely different places (20 paces from the original end point). So yes the order of instructions is usually very important.